# SSRS Execute and display data created by TSQL

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, plot

I have a TSQL scrip that populates coordinates as a table variable:

```
declare @reg_data table
(
    I int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    X float,
    Y float
)

insert into @reg_data
select field1, dbo.func(field1) from table Y where ...
```

In SSRS 2008 how can I plot Y vs. X in a chart with another dataset?

Answer (score 4):

You can only use one dataset in a chart in SSRS 2008. You'll need to create a dataset that combines X and Y first. Create a stored procedure that sets up your table variable and then use the code for your second dataset there to return a single dataset with both X and Y.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on how to do that? I do not have much experience with SSRS or TSQL

Comment: That's not an easy question to answer without knowing how you're getting X. You really need to have some TSQL experience to do this, but if you can give an example of how you plan to get the X value, I can try to point you in the right direction.

Comment: X is just 1, 2, ..., n (my x-values are going to be used for regression analysis)

Comment: ok - so @reg_date is going to contain X and y. You mention in your question that you want to plot this "with another dataset". What is that other dataset? And how would you plot this if you were doing this plotting manually (combining X, Y and the other dataset)?